# how to extend the timeout in bot framework composer?

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

how to extend the external request (https) timeout in bot framework composer?

I want to extend the timeout of the https request so that the bot waits till that and respond me with the output.. for every first call it is failing for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you seeing these timeouts? I assuming this may be in an http call and you are reffering to the 15 second timeout that happens when using Directline (WebChat, etc). If so, your best option is to use proactive messages. It's best practice to use proactive messages for any possibility of a long running process (calls to other APIs, etc) even if it might be just under. Please see here for more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-long-operations-guidance?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

There is also the *experimental* ImmediateAcceptAdapter (which essentially turns everything into a proactive message):
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/immediate-accept-adapter/csharp_dotnetcore

You would need to customize and modify the bot runtime.